# Transfer part of array to CUDA memory

Tags: arrays, memory, cuda

Suppose I have a dynamically allocated array of size `N * M` on host, which I use as a matrix (i.e. as 2D array). Now, i divide `M` into two parts, `cpuM` and `gpuM`. I wish to transfer part of that array to GPU, which is (pitched) array of `N * gpuM`. How do I do that?

So far I have:

```
cudaMemcpy3DParms cpy = { 0 };
cpy.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(h_mat, M * sizeof(TYPE), gpuM, N);
cpy.dstPtr = d_mat;
cpy.extent = make_cudaExtent(gpuM * sizeof(TYPE), N, 1);
cpy.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy3D(&cpy));
```

However, this doesn't work. I don't know where to specify number of elements to skip in `M` dimension (`cpuM`), which I obviously need.

So, what is the way to copy only part of array to GPU?

Comment: When you say "part", what do you mean? Do you want to transfer any arbitrary sized submatrix, or do you only need half the columns, or half the rows,. or what?

Comment: Parts as in some arbitrary number of elements of a row. For example, if matrix was `4x5 (NxM)`  and i want `cpuM=3` and `gpuM=2`, gpu would get 4x2 matrix, where elements are of index `[N][3]` and `[N][4]` (i.e. last two of every row) of the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close. What I nedded can be done with `srcPos` and/or `dstPos` which take a `cudaPos` structure which contains any desired offsets. Like:

```
cudaMemcpy3DParms cpy = { 0 };
cpy.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(h_mat, M * sizeof(TYPE), M, N);
cpy.srcPos = make_cudaPos(cpuM * sizeof(TYPE), 0, 0);
cpy.dstPtr = d_mat;
cpy.extent = make_cudaExtent(gpuM * sizeof(TYPE), N, 1);
cpy.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy3D(&cpy));
```